Rails. Validation with has_many through: association
I’m working on a Rails 7 application with the following models and associations.
For example, there are models and associations:
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_classifiers
  has_many :classifiers, through: :article_classifiers
end

class Classifier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_classifiers
  has_many :article, through: :article_classifiers
end

class ArticleClassifier < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :classifier
end

I need to validate the existence of Classifier objects before creating or updating an Article. In the controller, I receive a classifier_ids parameter, which is an array of IDs intended for association with the article. There's a possibility that one or more of these classifiers may have been deleted, necessitating a check before updating.
Rails automatically adds Article.classifier_ids and Article.classifier_ids= methods with such associations. Here’s how I've customized these methods along with adding an accessor and custom validation:
attr_accessor :temp_classifier_ids

def classifier_ids
  classifiers.pluck(:id)
end


# Here we automatically get ids from the request parameters of the controller  
def classifier_ids=(ids)
  ids = ids.compact_blank.map(&:to_i)
  self.temp_classifier_ids = ids
  self.classifiers = Classifier.where(id: ids)
end

validate :check_classifiers_existence

def check_classifiers_existence
  return if Classifier.classifiers_exist?(temp_classifier_ids)

  errors.add(:base, 'Classifier not exist')
end

This setup works, but I’m not certain it’s the most Rails-idiomatic approach. What would be the best practice for validating the existence of associated classifiers before saving in Rails?

Whats the actual requirement here? That an article should have one or more classifiers? That the classifiers should be valid? That only pre-existing classifiers can be used?

An article may contain several classifiers. The fact is that during the creation or updating of an article, classifiers can be deleted from the system. Therefore, before saving, it is necessary to check the availability of all the passed classifiers and show the error to the user

Do you try to prevent ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception or what is your final goal? Rails check it themselves before save and raise error

When you define has_many :classifiers association, it adds few methods
One of them is classifier_ids=
This method calls ids_writer
This ids writer checks ids before save (similiar way as your setup) and raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if ids are incosistent
Therefore if you need to prevent such error, you can catch it and add error to the model, something like
def classifier_ids=(ids)
  super
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  errors.add(:base, e.message)
end

You don't need additional accessor, monkey patched reader and validation

Yes, thank you! That's what I need. Your solution is quite simple and clear!

A tiny nitpick is that you might want to add a more user friendly message to the errors than the exception error message (which could be logged).

I tried the method from @mechnicov, but after a detailed review, we can conclude, the code snippet you provided, def classifier_ids=(ids), is not an ideal solution for invalidating a model because it is called before the update and validation process. Additionally, calling self.valid? inside the update method will clear all errors, including the ones added in classifier_ids=. This makes future validation impossible.
May be a better approach is to intercept the ids parameter and assign it to an instance variable, such as @params_ids. You can then create a custom validation method that uses this variable to add errors during the validation process.
Here's an example of how you can achieve this:
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  validate :custom_validation_method

 def classifier_ids=(ids)
    super
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    @params_ids = ids
  end

  def custom_validation_method
    # Add your custom validation logic here, using @params_ids
    if some_condition
      errors.add(:base, 'Your error message')
    end
  end
end

In the above example, the classifier_ids= method assigns the ids parameter to the @params_ids instance variable. Then, the custom_validation_method is a custom validation method that can access the @params_ids variable and add errors to the errors collection if necessary.
Using this approach, you can add errors during the validation process and use the valid? method to check if the model is valid or not. If there are errors, you can handle them accordingly.

BTW, all suggested options aren't resistant to race condition. Something like Classifier.transaction do; if Classifier.select('*').from(Classifier.where(id: ids).lock).count != ids.size; article.errors.add(:base, 'Classifier not exist'); next; end; article.save!; end should work. It is just an idea, you can apply it for you needs. It's better than some hacks with instance variables and accessors in the models
